# Populating MySQL database with 10 000 values

Tags: mysql, sql, batch-file

I want to create simple program that is going to populate MySQL database tables with some random values 10 000 times. I want to test the speed of inserting and reading in tables with two engines InnoDB (it's standard row oriented engine) and InfiniDB (specified column oriented engine). Any idea how to do this?
This is the example of one of the tables in my database:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tblVariable` (
  `idtblVariable` INT NOT NULL ,
   `name` VARCHAR(20) NULL ,
   `station_id` INT NULL ,  
   `description` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
   `id_history` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
   `type` ENUM('Analog','Digital') NOT NULL
)
```

so to explain..for idtblVariable that's going to be number from 1 to 10 000 random
name can be: PT1,..., PT10000
description for example is going to be just: a,a,a,a, 10 000 times
etc.
Client side is program, the inserting and reading is in C# with forms, classic application. Can this could be done in batch program???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a nother trick for populating numbers from 1 to 10000. If you create a temp table or a table variable and fill it with numbers from 0 to 9 like so:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP 
(Digit int);
INSERT INTO Temp VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);
```

Then you can generate numbers from 1 to 10000 like so:

```
INSERT INTO tblVariable (idtblVariable) 
SELECT id
FROM
(
SELECT t4.digit * 1000 + t3.digit * 100 + t2.digit * 10 + t1.digit + 1 AS id
FROM         TEMP AS t1
  CROSS JOIN TEMP AS t2
  CROSS JOIN TEMP AS t3
  CROSS JOIN TEMP AS t4
) t
```

### [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e85e/1)

Comment: what about other fields who are VARCHAR? can I use this method to populate those fields? thanks for this, I gona use this for sho

Comment: @MorsViolenta For the other fields you can use this method to to populate values in the shape `value1`, `value2`,.... `value100000` and so on. Is this enough for you??

Comment: yes, I just thinked about that. Thanks so much, you been so helpful!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via stored procedure, for example:

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `NewProc`()
BEGIN
 #Routine body goes here...
DECLARE counter INT;
DECLARE i INT;

SET i = 0;
SET counter = 10000;

WHILE i < counter DO
    INSERT INTO tblVariable (idtblVariable, name, /*Other fields*/) 
    VALUES (i, CONCAT('PT',i), /*Other values*/);
    SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;

END;
```

You can remove/update the part `DEFINER =`root`@`localhost if you experience problems with MySQL permissions.
**UPDATE**: Then, after stored procedure creation, you can call the procedure like this:

```
CALL NewProc;
```

Comment: this is quite good, but Mahmoud Gamal give me simple soultion for id. But i gona use this for some other fields who are varchar, this solution does that no?

Comment: Yes, you can use it with the varchar fields also, mark the CONCAT() function - it does the concatenate of the strings

Comment: thanks, I gona use the solution that Mahmoud Gamal give me for some tables, and yours for others, to see which is the best for testing. Thanks anyway so much!

Comment: This method on my developer machine(Intel Core i3@3Ghz with 8Gb DDR3 and Intel SSD 120GB) it took 3.25 seconds to insert 10000 records in database, both with ID and names

Comment: that's not bad, I have similar machine but with HDD of 500GB. Can you tell me how did you measured time of inserting? And how I can measure time of reading? And how to create this procedure. I never worked with stored procedure? If you have time just send me explanation at mail mctoxic88@gmail.com. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Here is the quick resume for stored procedures - http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx

Comment: I somehow managed to create and run procedure. This new mysql workbench is a little bit confusing. Thanks for so much help.

Comment: You can use a far better, user-friendly and also free interface, download HeidiSQL :)